# Program reads in file using pass by value with reference parameters in c++

Tags: c++, parameters, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

here is my code i am using. Now I know arrays might be the better choice but this is how the professor wants it done. When I try running the program it just goes in an infinite loop but seems like I am almost there. I am new to c++ and do not know the language well just the basics. The program needs to first read in item, cost, and number. Then read in the different selling prices later on and then output the item name, cost of item, selling price, gross profit and net profit.I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the direction of where I am going wrong.

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//all functions needed for this project
void  readSellingFile(ifstream &fp, int &number);
double grossprofit(double total, double cost);
double netprofit(double gross, double total);
void getDataFile(ifstream &fp, string &item, int &number, double &cost);
void display(string item,double total, double cost,double gross,double net);

//main function starts here
  int main()
-=--:----F1  project5.cpp   Top L1     (C++/l Abbrev)---------------------------
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
File Edit Options Buffers Tools C++ Help
  fp>>number;
  fp>>cost;
}

//the selling cost of the item
void readSellingFile(ifstream &fp, double &selling)
{
  double total;
    fp>>selling;
  selling+=total;

}

//calculates the gross profit
double grossprofit(double total,double cost)
{
  double gross;
  gross=total-cost;
  return gross;
}

//calculates the net profit
double netprofit(double gross,double total)
{
  double net;
  net=gross-(.06*total)-(.10*total);
  return net;
}

//prints out the results
void display(string item, double total, double cost ,double gross, double net)
  {
    cout<<"Item:\t\t"<<item<<endl;
    cout<<"cost:\t\t$"<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<cost<<endl;
    cout<<"Selling price:\t$"<<setprecision(2)<<total<<endl;
    cout<<"Gross Profit: \t$"<<setprecision(2)<<gross<<endl;
    cout<<"Net Profit: \t$"<<setprecision(2)<<net<<endl;
   }
```

Comment: `selling+=total;` invokes undefined behavior. You never assigned any value to `total`, and it is therefore *indeterminate*. I think the prior line should be `fp >> total;`, though I question the names of the params and local vars in this function. It isn't exactly clear.

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah sorry Im new to this and reading in a file confuses me so I know a lot of it is confusing. I have a program where the user does it manually but now we need it to read in a file instead and it really through me off.

Comment: Stop writing programs until you know how to use a debugger.  If you cannot use a debugger, you cannot develop software.

Comment: @MartinJames Well since I am taking a class and this is a project due that is not really an option at this time. thanks though

Comment: You seem to have some emacs lines obliterating part of your `main` function.